# Segmentation fault when adding a pointer to an array

Tags: c++

I have created two classes, Class and Students. In the Class constructor, I need to initialize an array of pointers (pStudents) to Student objects dynamically (I can't use vectors), initialized to null. When I add a student to the class using the function addStudent, I want to be able to search the array of pointers for the first null address and then assign the student to that spot in the array. If the student is already in the class, I also want to be able to search the array to see if this student is already there.

When I try to compile the program, I get a segmentation fault. I know it has to do with the way I am using heap memory when I create the pStudents array, but I am unsure of how to resolve this.

Here is how I have declared the array in the Class header file:

```
Student **ptrStudents;
```

This is the constructor for the Class objects. For now, I'm using the arbitrary size 40 for the array.

```
Class::Class()
{
Student **ptrStudents = new Student*[40];
}
```

Here is the function addStudents, which takes a pointer to a student object as its argument. Note that string name is a data field for all students.

```
Class::addStudents(Student *student)
{

 string name = student -> getName();
 string nameTemp;

 for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
 {
    if (ptrStudents[i] != 0)
    {
       nameTemp = ptrStudents[i] -> getName();  
       if (name == nameTemp)
       {
         cout << "This student is already in the class." << endl;
         return;
        }
    }

else if (ptrStudents[i] == 0)
{
        ptrStudents[i] = student;
        return;
}
```

And here is the main function I'm working with:

```
int main ()
{
    Class Economics;
    Student student1("Hannah");
    Economics.addStudent(&student1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `ptrFlights[i]`?

Comment: Do you get a segfault when you compile or when you run? Did you mean you get an error when compiling?

Comment: Sorry, fixed my typo to ptrStudents. I should have been more clear, it's when I run the program. It will compile but not run correctly (the editor I'm working combines both steps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize each of the pointers in the array to NULL. Change your constructor to this:

```
Class::Class()
{
ptrStudents = new Student*[40];
for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    ptrStudents[i] = 0;    //NULL
}
```

When you create a pointer, it is not NULL-initialized automatically. So what's happening is you have a bunch of random pointers to garbage data, and when you reach the line

```
if (ptrStudents[i] != 0)
```

they all pass because they're not NULL, even though they are unusable.

Whoops, I missed a big one, even when I copied your code (thank you, John). You should not re-declare the ptrStudents array; that creates a local array in your constructor, instead of initializing the member array.

Comment: I have tried doing that and still get an error unfortunately.

Comment: @JesseP_613 That's because of your other error. Read the other answers.

Comment: My apologies, I steered you wrong with my first answer. I overlooked the fact that you were re-declaring the array in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks. I have fixed my code to initialize the values of the array in the constructor (ptrStudents = new Student*[40] and then the loop). But to be clear, how should I declare the array in the header file?

Comment: The same way you did before: `Student **ptrStudents;`

Answer (score 0):

The array declared in the class header is never initialized.

> `Student **ptrStudents = new Student*[40];`

This declares a local variable and initialize it with the new array.

Change it to:

`ptrStudents = new Student*[40];`

Answer (score 0):

At least two errors

Firstly you should initalise your array values to NULL (as Parker Kemp says)

Secondly you have declared a local variable in your constructor called ptrStudents which *hides* the class variable also called ptrStudents. You should remove that declaration. So like this

```
Class::Class()
{
    ptrStudents = new Student*[40];
    for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        ptrStudents[i] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing from what you have shown

```
Class::Class()
{
    Student **ptrStudents = new Student*[40];
}
```

declares a new `Student **ptrStudents`. To initialize the member `ptrStudents` you don't have to declare it. It is already declared.

What you want is

```
Class::Class()
{
    ptrStudents = new Student*[40];
}
```